# Is put and call must have to same iv for the put call parity to hold and why?

Tags: options, implied-volatility, put-call-parity

and would the dividend pay affect this relationship? and is this relationship apply on american option too?

Comment: Put call parity is a relationship between real variables. You don't even have to know how to price a call or put to justify call put parity, let alone make a point about IV.